# How do you set the Babel environment variable (BABEL_ENV) when using Babel Loader with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, environment-variables, babeljs, babel-loader

How do you set the Babel environment variable (i.e. BABEL_ENV) when using the 'babel-loader' Webpack plugin?

I want to be able to use different Babel configurations while using Webpack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to set a specific option in the 'babel-loader' rule within your Webpack config file.

In Babel Loader v8+, the option is called `envName`, but I believe that it is called `forceEnv` in previous versions.

**webpack.config.js**

```
rules: [
  {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      envName: 'yourEnvironmentName',  // use this for Babel Loader v8+
      forceEnv: 'yourEnvironmentName'  // use this for lower versions
    }
  }
]
```